# Script to convert text inside <li> lines into search links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, anchor

I have several DIVs with LIs inside, but I want to convert the text inside of LIs that belongs to a specific DIV id, example:

```
<div id="filtro_mod">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>HP DesignJet 100 Printer series</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>HP DesignJet 100 Printer - C7796A</li>
        <li>HP DesignJet 100 Printer - C7796AR</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><strong>HP DesignJet 100 Plus Printer series</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>HP DesignJet 100 Plus Printer - C7796C</li>
        <li>HP DesignJet 100 Plus Printer - C7796CR</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**So I pretend to convert this:**

```
<li>HP DesignJet 100 Printer - C7796A</li>
```

**Into this:**

```
<li><a href="http://mywebsite.com/pesquisa?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=HP%20DesignJet%20100%20Printer%20-%20C7796A+&submit_search=">HP DesignJet 100 Printer - C7796A</a></li>
```

However in some lines there is a STRONG inside an LI with others LIs. Example:

```
<ul>
  <li><strong>HP DesignJet 100 Printer series</strong>
    <ul>
      <li>HP DesignJet 100 Printer - C7796A</li>
      <li>HP DesignJet 100 Printer - C7796AR</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think this is possible like a script to convert plain urls text into links like this:

[How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: when you say "pretend" do you actually mean "try"?

Comment: @webeno, I think they mean pretend, because it doesn't look like they've tried anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#filtro_mod li li').each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<a href="theurl.com?desc=' + html + '">' + html + '</a>');
});
```

Comment: This is so destructive.

Comment: Just consider the top-most `li` elements! Apart from this, you haven't call the `html` method, missing `()`.

Comment: No problem, please use a less generic selector!

Comment: @Vohuman I modified so that it's selecting by any `li` within the `div` given. Other than that, not sure what you might be looking for from the answer.

Comment: Isn't `$('#filtro_mod li li')` better?

Comment: @Vohuman won't that select *only* second-level li's? Doesn't he want them all changed? Edit: I misread the question, Vohuman is right.

Comment: I try this but dont work see the page http://hpecas.com/pt/correias-para-impressoras-hp/q1292-67026-carriage-belt-for-printer-hp-designjet-100-100-110-110-111-120-130-series_707.html

Comment: @SérgioMartins What's the issue?

Comment: You need to URL escape the `html` variable

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand much, not to say anything of programming.
Would you can give an example.

Comment: I'm testing the above example this page http://hpecas.com/pt/correias-para-impressoras-hp/q1292-67026-carriage-belt-for-printer-hp-designjet-100-100-110-110-111-120-130-series_707.html

Comment: @SérgioMartins Put a demo into jsFiddle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Comment: I try on http://jsfiddle.net/bmkdvLge/1/ work fine but on my website dont http://hpecas.com/en/belts-for-hp-printers/q1292-67026-carriage-belt-for-printer-hp-designjet-100-100-110-110-111-120-130-series_707.html

Comment: @SérgioMartins Well, not to be rude but that could be caused by dozens of things. Starting with, make sure you've included jQuery before running that script. The answer provided works, though.

Comment: Just one more thing who to include encodeURIComponent

Comment: @SérgioMartins as Matt mentioned, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent